# identify which is a substring/which is not or sub-sequences/sequence

Tags: python, string, substring

I'm simplifying a lot but I  have a load of strings that are sequences like:

```
`"A-B-C-D-E"`, "A-B-C", "A-B", "B-C", "D-E"
```

but could just as easily be lists of letters.

They are all from a limited number of letters, and one of the sequence contains all the others. My question is for a set of these sequences how to determine which is the one that contains all the others/identify the substrings versus the complete sequence/flatten into one to end up with just:

```
"A-B-C-D-E"
```

In python

Comment: Can you simply check for the longest string?

Comment: Sometimes the simplicity of a task gets you away from doing that. If you don't have any repetitive character well simply check the length as @Cyber said. :-)

Comment: And if there are repetitive characters just convert your strings into sets and then check the maximum length one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do as Cyber and Muradin said:
I am mostly a java guy, so I will give you a code-like algorithm to perform your task. Here it is:

If lengthOfString(String string) == 9
    check each of the characters of the string to see if they are unique
    if there is only one combination of the letters, then check the positions of the letters, and compare them with what
    you expect it to be
    else, if there are several combinations of the letters, then check each position and compare it with the letter you would expect.

```
Hope that solves your problem
```